# What is the recommended way to serialize a collection of spaCy Docs?

Tags: python, spacy

I'm working with very large collections of short texts that I need to annotate and save to disk. Ideally I'd like to save/load them as spaCy `Doc` objects. Obviously I don't want to save the `Language` or `Vocab` objects more than once (but happy to save/load it once for a collection of  `Doc`s).

The `Doc` object has a `to_disk` method and a `to_bytes` method, but it's not immediately obvious to me how to save a bunch of documents to the same file. Is there a preferred way of doing this? I'm looking for something as space-efficient as possible.

Currently I'm doing this, which I'm not very happy with:

```
def serialize_docs(docs):
    """
    Writes spaCy Doc objects to a newline-delimited string that can be used to load them later, 
    given the same Vocab object that was used to create them.
    """
    return '\n'.join([codecs.encode(doc.to_bytes(), 'hex') for doc in docs])

def write_docs(filename, docs):
    """
    Writes spaCy Doc objects to a file.
    """
    serialized_docs = seralize_docs(docs)
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(serialized_docs)
```

Comment: Please check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
Add your code , what have you tried.

Answer (score 6):

As of Spacy 2.2, the correct answer is to use [DocBin](https://spacy.io/api/docbin).

As the [Spacy docs](https://spacy.io/usage/saving-loading#docs) now say,

> If you’re working with lots of data, you’ll probably need to pass
>   analyses between machines, either to use something like Dask or Spark,
>   or even just to save out work to disk. Often it’s sufficient to use
>   the Doc.to_array functionality for this, and just serialize the numpy
>   arrays – but other times you want a more general way to save and
>   restore Doc objects.
>
> The DocBin class makes it easy to serialize and deserialize a
>   collection of Doc objects together, and is much more efficient than
>   calling Doc.to_bytes on each individual Doc object. You can also
>   control what data gets saved, and you can merge pallets together for
>   easy map/reduce-style processing.

Example

```py
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import DocBin

doc_bin = DocBin(attrs=["LEMMA", "ENT_IOB", "ENT_TYPE"], store_user_data=True)
texts = ["Some text", "Lots of texts...", "..."]
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
for doc in nlp.pipe(texts):
    doc_bin.add(doc)
bytes_data = doc_bin.to_bytes()

# Deserialize later, e.g. in a new process
nlp = spacy.blank("en")
doc_bin = DocBin().from_bytes(bytes_data)
docs = list(doc_bin.get_docs(nlp.vocab))
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using the same nlp object, the Vocab can be used across all your different doc objects, so it just needs to be serialized once.

My approach for serialization would be:

- serialize the shared Vocab
- serialize every doc object using the to_disk method into different files in a docs folder

For getting back your doc objects:

- Deserialize the shared Vocab
- Deserialize every doc object in the docs folder and append them to a list.

The following code should work:

```
import spacy
import glob
import os
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
texts = ["Hello friend", "how is your day?", "I wish you all the best"]
docs = [nlp(text) for text in texts]

''' Serialization '''
# Serialize vocab
nlp.vocab.to_disk('vocab/vocab.txt')

# Serialize docs
for i, doc in enumerate(docs):
    doc.to_disk('docs/{}.txt'.format(i))


''' Deserialization '''
docs = []
# deserialize vocab - common for all docs
nlp_vocab = spacy.vocab.Vocab().from_disk('vocab/vocab.txt')

# deserialize docs
path = os.path.join('docs', '*.txt')
files = glob.iglob(path)
for file in files:
    docs.append(spacy.tokens.Doc(nlp_vocab).from_disk(file))
```

I think is as much space efficient as it can get.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Here for me the issue was that it does not load the annotations (like POS tags)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert (yet), but have tried pickling to handle a similar situation and it seems to work just fine:

```
import spacy
import pickle
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
texts = ["Hello friend", "how is your day?", "I wish you all the best"]
docs = [nlp(text) for text in texts]

''' Serialization '''
# Serialize vocab (actually the whole NLP ojbect)
pickle.dump(nlp, open("vocab/vocab and nlp Obj.pickle", "wb"))
pickle.dump(docs, open("docs/serialized docs.pickle", "wb"))

''' Deserialization '''
nlp = pickle.load(open("vocab/vocab and nlp Obj.pickle", "rb"))
docs = pickle.load(open("docs/serialized docs.pickle", "rb"))
```