# chunk/serialize a collections of spaCy Docs for training?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I have annotated data that I want to train a model on that using spaCy, the problem is the size of corpus (also my training data) is too large, spaCy complain about that in this way

```
here we should Consider splitting up your documents into several doc bins and serializing each separately. spacy.Corpus.v1 will search recursively for all *.spacy files if you provide a directory instead of a filename as the 'path'.
```

here is my code:

```
db = DocBin()   #[E870] Could not serialize the DocBin because it is too large. Consider splitting up your documents into several doc bins and serializing each separately. spacy.Corpus.v1 will search recursively for all *.spacy files if you provide a directory instead of a filename as the 'path'.

for text, annot in tqdm(train):  # data in previous format
    doc = nlp_lg.make_doc(text)  # create doc object from text
    ents = []
    for start, end, label in annot["entities"]:  # add character indexes
        span = doc.char_span(start, end, label=label, alignment_mode="contract")
        if span is not None:
            ents.append(span)
    doc.ents = ents  # label the text with the ents
    db.add(doc)
db.to_disk("./train.spacy")  # save the docbin object
```

The last line is where the spacy complain when I would choose a big corpus.

I know, I need to probably to chunk the doc (binary data ) read the chunk with star.

In which way you would recommend, I should start?

I saw this page,
[What is the recommended way to serialize a collection of spaCy Docs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49618917/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-serialize-a-collection-of-spacy-docs)

but the structure looks a bit different.